# Is there a Hausdorff space that is also a group such that the group operation is continuous but the inversion map is not continuous?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

The question is from the definition of to topological group. I can find an example such that the inversion map is continuous but the group operation is not continuous, but I cannot find an example such that the group operation is continuous but the inversion map is not continuous.

I guess that such a space (if exists) is not T3, but I just know some easy examples of Hausdorff but not T3 spaces.

Comment: The Sorgenfrey line. This space is even Hausdorff and (monotonically) normal and paracompact.

Comment: If the space is completely metrizable,  then inversion is automatically continuous.  In fact, you can assume less: multiplication is separately continuous.  The proof uses Baire category theorem, but the nonseparable case is tricky.

Comment: @Tyrone ... Would this work taking the rationals with the Sorgenfrey topology?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I believe it suffices to assume that the underlying space is Cech complete CRH. $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ isn't Cech complete. It's second-countable and regular so metrisable, but doesn't have any isolated points so isn't complete. In particular it can't even be Baire. Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I meant: is the Sorgenfrey rationals an example where $+$ is continuous, but $x \mapsto -x$ is not.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar to answer your question, yes $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ is a countable, metrisable example. My previous comment explains why there is no contradiction to the fact contained in your initial comment (I thought this is what you were asking before).

Comment: If you're looking for references on this, the term for a group equipped with a topology with continuous multiplication (but not necessarily continuous inverse) is a "paratopological group".  See for instance the answers to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130419/suppose-g-mathcal-t-is-a-paratopological-group-and-a-b-in-g-and-every-nei/209491#209491